# How can I remove nut grass growing in amongst dwarf mondo grass?

Tags: weed-control, weeds

[image: NutGrass growing amongst Dwarf Mondo Grass]

Hi there,

The above photograph is of NutGrass growing in amongst Dwarf Mondo Grass, is there a selective herbicide or other method available to remove it with minor impact to the dwarf mondo grass?

Thankyou!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You pull it out. It is a sedge so it is difficult to find an effective herbicide.

Comment: Yeah, that is brutal, but the longer you wait, the worse it will be.  Each time you pull a sedge, it then regrows but uses up reserves.  Don't let them get to 4/5 blades.  You could use a foam brush dipped in weed killer to selectively kill.